# Xcode Instruments is throwing an error about non-existent iOS app extension

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments

This is the error I'm getting when I try to run an Instruments network trace on my iPhone:

[image: Instruments error message]

This extension is part of the the Wide Protect app, which I've deleted. I've already tried restarting the iPhone and deleting/reinstalling XCode. Looks like some crud is getting left behind, but is it on the iPhone or on my Mac?

Comment: Have you checked with the developers of the Wide Protect app to ensure you uninstalled it correctly?

Comment: It's an iOS app, so deleting _should_ have uninstalled everything. And yes, I've emailed the developer, no reply yet.

Comment: You might have a better response to this on the Apple Developer forums or on SE than here.  While it's technically on-topic, those other sites probably deal with issues like this more than this site.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that...I'll cross post

Comment: We generally don't like cross-posting on the SE sites.  I would recommend asking a moderator to move this question to SO.